# Custom filter the children of antd table dataSource

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using `antd`'s `table` component. I want to be able to filter the nodes down to any descendant.

I'm following the example of `antd`'s [custom filter](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel).
The example is not a tree structure, so here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2x4nxnpz9) with the right setup.

`onFilter` seems to only loop over the root nodes. I don't know how to display Tesla > Model 3 it I type '3' in the search input. I know I have to return `true` for Tesla, but I still don't understand how to then also return `true` for `Model 3`

**data**

```
const data = [
      {
        key: "13",
        name: "Tesla",
        data: {
          description: "Car manufacturer",
          type: "Organization"
        },
        children: [
          {
            key: "4444",
            name: "Model S",
            data: {
              description: "The fastest",
              type: "Project"
            }
          },
          {
            key: "1444323",
            name: "Model 3",
            data: {
              description: "The cheapest",
              type: "Project"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        key: "1",
        name: "Microsoft",
        data: {
          description: "#1 software company",
          type: "Organization"
        }
      }
    ];
```

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
  };

  getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters,
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input          
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}              
        />
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
          icon="search"
        >
          Search
        </Button>            
      </div>
    ),

    // onFilter seems to only loop over root nodes
    onFilter: (value, record) => record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),    
    render: (text) => (
      <Highlighter
        ...
      />
    ),
  })     

  render() {
    const columns = [{
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      ...this.getColumnSearchProps('name'),
    }];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to get a node's descendant values (based on `dataIndex`) and filter for any of those having the search text too.

This would go inside of getColumnSearchProps *before* the return value:

```
const getDescendantValues = (record) => {
        const values = [];
        (function recurse(record) {
            values.push(record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase());
            record.children.forEach(recurse);
        })(record);
        return values;
    }
```

...and this would be the updated onFilter:

```
onFilter: (value, record) => {
  const recordName = record[dataIndex] || record.data[dataIndex];
  const searchLower = value.toLowerCase();
  return recordName
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchLower)
      ||
      getDescendantValues(record).some(descValue => descValue.includes(searchLower));
  }
```

I've forked your sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/10jp9wql1j

...it includes all the root nodes with any descendant that satisfies your search condition. However it does *not* filter out the other descendant nodes that do not satisfy your search condition, unfortunately.

Comment: No idea how I missed that 2 years ago. I just needed this again, and found your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, it seems like there isn't a great way to do this.

I'm using mobx and React, but the basic principles can be applied elsewhere. The idea is to give the rows you want to filter out a CSS class name to hide them.

I used mobx to create an observable of the checked filter values. You could also use React.useState. Using your example, let's say the observable is called `ModelFilters`. Then, on the table component, add rowClassName:

```
        <Table
        ...
        rowClassName={(record, index) => {
            if (ModelFilters.includes(record.model) ) {
                return ''
            }
            return 'some-css-class-with-display-none'
        }}
    />
```

Any record that doesn't have a model that matches the selected filters will be hidden. Of course, if you are using the table to manipulate/submit data, you will have to handle that elsewhere. This is just for displaying purposes.